# Como fazer com que meu Programa acessa a net?

Tags: java, conexão

Na verdade quero criar um programa que avise-me que a minha conexão com a internet caiu, mas quero criá-lo. Tenho um pouco de noção em java, poo, mas queria saber por onde começo.

Tenho que importar alguma ferramenta que acessa a net? S se o programa conseguir acessar a net?

Exemplo frouxo aqui só para entenderem:

```
if (Se o acesso == true) {
    System.out.print("não faça nada");
} else {
    Comando para apitar um alarme etc???
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente isso:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class ApitaQuandoCaiInternet {

    // Método que verifica se a internet está conectada.
    // Para descobrir se a internet está conectada, ele tenta conectar no google.
    public static boolean internetOk() {
        String site = "http://www.google.com";
        URL url;

        // Cria uma URL para o site do google.
        try {
            url = new URL(site);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // Este erro não deve ocorrer nunca, pois a URL informada é sabidamente
            // bem formada. Assim sendo, lança o AssertionError que é o erro para
            // representar situações inesperadas que acredita(va)-se que nunca ocorreriam.
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }

        HttpURLConnection c = null;
        try {

            // Abre uma conexão com o site do google.
            c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            c.setUseCaches(false);
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.connect();

            // Força o download de alguma resposta ao solicitar o código de status.
            // Ver https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes
            // Como o propósito é apenas conectar ou não, não precisamos fazer
            // nada com o código.
            int status = c.getResponseCode();

            // Conseguiu fazer o download, estamos online.
            return true;

        // Erro no download. Estamos offline.
        } catch (IOException x) {
            return false;

        // Fecha a conexão ao final, independente do resultado.
        } finally {
            if (c != null) c.disconnect();
        }
    }

    // Método que faz um barulho.
    public static void beep() {
        java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (true) {
            // Se a internet tiver caído, faz um barulho.
            if (!internetOk()) beep();

            // Espera 10 segundos e tenta de novo depois.
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Beleza, pode me explicar sobre os import?  ficou bom testei aq

Comment: @Den Os imports são apenas bibliotecas e classes já existentes dentro da JDK que são utilizadas. `java.net.URL` é uma classe que, como o nome já diz, serve para representar URLs. Já a classe `java.net.HttpURLConnection` é a classe que representa uma conexão HTTP. `java.io.IOException` e `java.net.MalformedURLException` são algumas exceções que podem aparecer.

Comment: Cara Muito obrigado pelo esforço ficou top seu cod. Mais velho eu preciso aprender a fazer isso, vi que vc abriu um metodo la e talz.. tem como me explicar passo a passo, vi que pois os comentarios.. mais tenho que sugar kkkk

Comment: entendi sobre as bibliotecas, mais e os comandos dessa biblioteca?

Comment: exemplo response cod?

Comment: @Den Como o propósito é apenas conectar ou não, não precisamos fazer nada com o código. Se o código de status já foi devolvido ao invés de dar uma exceção, é porque ele conseguiu conectar. Se a ideia fosse fazer download ou upload de alguma coisa, então verificar o código seria importante e ainda seriam necessárias várias outras operações, mas como o propósito é apenas conectar, então não precisamos verificar o código.

Comment: Entendi, realmente este é o propósito, verificar se teve conexão, porém , 
 eu queria entender sobre os códigos que você utilizou depois de importar as lib ? eu to te pedindo pq eu não conheço essas lib :/

Comment: @Den Você pode ver todas as que tem na JDK aqui: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/ - Mas são algumas milhares de classes. E há um monte que você vai achar fora da JDK. Para conhecer isso tudo é necessário fazer cursos, treinamentos, devorar livros, fazer experimentos, praticar bastante e quebrar a cabeça. Às vezes, algumas dessas classes e métodos eu levo anos para aprender a usar, e certamente há muita coisa que ainda não sei usar ou nem mesmo sei que existe. Entretanto, graças ao StackOverflow e sites semelhantes, podemos compartilhar experiências para aprendermos muito mais rápido.

Comment: Verdade tu tem total razão, Mais se não e tu me mostrar este código eu nem ia saber sobre essas classes, mais fazer o que né. igual o som? nem sabia, se fosse eu, eu ia mandar entrar no cmd e dar start som.mp3 kkkkkk sei dessas classe não

Comment: Mais vou estudar em cima deste seu código,

Comment: e depois vou jogar ele no swing

Comment: tem como alterar o som?

Comment: @Den Ele usa o som configurado como beep padrão do sistema operacional. Dá para mudar sim, uma forma (gambiarrosa) seria o `start som.mp3`, mas certamente há formas melhores. Vou pesquisar mais, e quando terminar, edito a resposta.

Comment: Ta beleza Obrigado por enquanto